# Copying Directories in a non-static environment?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, directory, copying

Can some one give me a hint/example of copying a directory in a non-static environment?
I tried to look it up but no such luck.

```
    private void copybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedPath = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        copydirectories(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath, @"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath + " - Copy");
    }

    public void copydirectories()
    {
        try
        {
            string selectedPath = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath);
            DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath);

            if (!source.Exists)
                return;
            if (!target.Exists)
                target.Create();

            DirectoryInfo[] sourceDirectories = source.GetDirectories();    
            for(int j = 0; j < sourceDirectories.Length; ++j)
            {
                copydirectories(sourceDirectories[j].FullName,target.FullName +"\\" + sourceDirectories[j].Name);
            }
            datemodified.Refresh();

   }
```

That got to takes 2 arguments error

Comment: Could you describe the characteristics of this *non-static environment*? What makes an environment *non-static*? In addition to that, in order to better understand your question, you might also want to explain what makes an environment being *static*?

Comment: Non static environment?  put your relevant code that causing error.

Comment: Its to be copied when a button is clicked...it gets its destination (some of it) from a user, using a combo box

Comment: You mean copy a directory tree? Like this: http://xneuron.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/copy-directory-and-its-content-to-another-directory-in-c/ ?

Comment: Maybe string concatenation with a variable might help you invoke the necessary method?

Comment: yes, but its going to be in the same main directory...basically all im trying to do is making a clone of a folder within the same Main directory

Comment: Did you look at the `System.IO.Path` class and its methods? Also please provide concrete examples of your directory structure to better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @heist: What do you mean with "same main directory"?

Comment: The code you provided is incorrect, your method `copydirectories` have no parameters, but you are clearly trying to call it with some

Comment: The folder is in C:\Mavro\MavBridge\ I want it to stay in there but all of its contents copied...lets say I have a folder called Data...i want the second copy to be in the same directory, C:\Mavro\MavBridge\, but just be called Data - Copy

Comment: @Patrick thats why im trying to look for an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code at http://xneuron.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/copy-directory-and-its-content-to-another-directory-in-c/

```
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) {
    // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(target.FullName)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
    }

    // Copy each file into its new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles()) {
        Console.WriteLine(@”Copying {0}\{1}”, target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories()) {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = 
            target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

makes it easy, just call it with

```
CopyAll(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath),
        new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\" + selectedPath + " - Copy"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to create function with 2 arguments?

```
public void copydirectories(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
            DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(destinationPath);
```